# clockKeeper function. Program 'works' but values are printed out in wrong order?

Tags: c, datetime, time, structure

I've written a function that acts as a clock. It will add one second on to the time(that is input) and will then will give the new time in military time.

If the new time is past midnight, then it will update the date (for the next day), taking into account months, years and whether it's a leap year.

The program runs ALMOST perfectly.

If the time updated is before midnight then it all works fine, like this:

***Okay, so choose your date:
22/07/2016
Now choose your time:
21:53:22
This is the new time: 21:53:23
This is the date: 22/7/2016***

But if it IS past midnight, then the time and date are printed out in the wrong order, like this:

***Okay, so choose your date:
21/07/2016
Now choose your time:
23:59:59
This is the new time: 7:22:2016
This is the date: 0/0/0***

Also notice, how the day and month have been switched around too!

This has left me pretty confused for quite some time, I'd appreciate any suggestions please.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
}dateAndTime;

// Function Declarations

dateAndTime timeUpdate (dateAndTime);
dateAndTime dateUpdate (dateAndTime);
dateAndTime clockKeeper (dateAndTime);
int numberOfDays (dateAndTime);
bool isLeapYear(dateAndTime);

int main (void)
{
    // Two functions of struct dateAndTime. 

    dateAndTime timeDate, newTimeDate;

    // Enter in dates and time

    printf("Okay, so choose your date:\n");
    scanf("%i/%i/%i", &timeDate.day, &timeDate.month, &timeDate.year);

    printf("Now choose your time:\n");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &timeDate.hours, &timeDate.minutes, &timeDate.seconds);

    // Call clockKeeper function, store new values in newTimeDate

    newTimeDate = clockKeeper(timeDate);

    //print updated time and date

    printf("This is the new time: %i:%i:%i\n", newTimeDate.hours, newTimeDate.minutes, newTimeDate.seconds);
    printf("This is the date: %i/%i/%i\n", newTimeDate.day, newTimeDate.month, newTimeDate.year);

}


// This function calls the timeUpdate function. If it's the new time is past midnight, call dateUpdate function

dateAndTime clockKeeper (dateAndTime timeDate)
{
    dateAndTime newTimeDate = timeUpdate (timeDate);

    if(newTimeDate.hours < timeDate.hours)
    {
        newTimeDate = dateUpdate(timeDate);
    }

    return newTimeDate;
}


// Update time

dateAndTime timeUpdate (dateAndTime now)
{
    now.seconds++;

    if(now.seconds == 60)
    {
        now.seconds = 0;
        now.minutes++;

        if(now.minutes == 60)
        {
            now.minutes = 0;
            now.hours++;

            if(now.hours == 24)
            {
            now.hours = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return now;
}


// Update date

dateAndTime dateUpdate (dateAndTime date)
{
    dateAndTime newDate;

    // call function to check how many days are in the month
    int numberOfDays (dateAndTime d);

    if(date.day != numberOfDays (date))
    {
        newDate = (dateAndTime) {date.month, date.day + 1, date.year};
    }
    else if(date.month == 12)
    {
        newDate = (dateAndTime) {1, 1, date.year + 1};
    }
    else
    {
        newDate = (dateAndTime) {date.month + 1, 1, date.year};
    }

    return newDate;
}

int numberOfDays (dateAndTime d)
{
    int days;

    //call function to check if it's a leap year so amount of days in february can be upated.
    bool isLeapYear (dateAndTime d);
    const int daysPerMonth[12] =
        {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    if(isLeapYear (d) && d.month == 2)
    {
        days = 29;
    }
    else
    {
        days = daysPerMonth[d.month - 1];
    }

    return days;
}

bool isLeapYear(dateAndTime d)
{
    bool leapYearFlag;

    if ( (d.year % 4 == 0 && d.year % d.year % 100 != 0) || d.year % 400 == 0)
    {
        leapYearFlag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        leapYearFlag = false;
    }

    return leapYearFlag;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The perfect opportunity to use a debugger.

Comment: I'm positive lines like `newDate = (dateAndTime) {date.month, date.day + 1, date.year};` aren't doing what you think they are. I suggest you review that area of your code. And I'm also pretty sure that `newTimeDate = dateUpdate(timeDate);` is not using your updated time values either. Should be `newTimeDate = dateUpdate(newTimeDate);`

Comment: Ahh, I don't know how to do that. I'm on chapter 8(Structures) in 'Programming in C'. I'm finishing the last exercise before getting onto Character Strings.

Debugging is chapter 17. The author has specifically asked for readers not to look ahead until each chapter it's exercises have been completed :s

Comment: @WhozCraig, I switched to `newTimeDate = dateUpdate(newTimeDate);`, that worked thank you.

I didn't need to change anything to `newDate = (dateAndTime) {date.month, date.day + 1, date.year};` though?

I'm can't work out why that fix to the function call worked. After all, the program always calculated the right values, it just printed them out in the wrong order :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newDate = (dateAndTime) {date.month + 1, 1, date.year};
```

You're basically saying that those 3 integers should be copied to first 3 integers of your dateAndTime struct, leaving other 3 default-initialized to 0.

What you should be doing is

```
newDate = (dateAndTime) {date.hours, date.minutes, date.seconds, date.month + 1, 1, date.year};
```

Your struct is printed in the correct order; the compound literal is just wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense...

But, please see my last comment to @WhozCraig above. I managed to get the program to work without making the amendment you suggested.

Which makes no sense to me because I know you're right!

Can you explain this?

Comment: @MattCleary possibly by accident, since if compiled without my changes, the program still outputs wrong values on my compiler.

Comment: @MattCleary but you should include both fixes, since they are both mandatory for correct program execution.